# Java 8 Consumer and side effects

Tags: java, java-8, consumer

I am new to Java 8, I came across Consumer java doc and it says, "Consumer is expected to operate via side-effects." Could somebody please explain why it is said so ?

Comment: If you're not used to functional programming, that language won't mean much to you. The idea is that "pure" functions should only read from their inputs, and only write to their return values (so there will be no side effects - the only effect of running the function is that you get the return value.) Functions that change something (modify a data structure, run IO, etc), are said to have side effects. A function without a return value had better have side effects, or else it isn't doing anything.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Does throwing exception from the method count as side effect?

Answer (score 20):

Consumer has method `accept` with the following signature

```
void accept(T t);
```

The method takes t as an input and doesn't return anything (void), and hence you can't return anything from it and replace the method call with the value it returns.

An example of a side effect would a print statement,

```
list.stream.foreach(System.out::println);
```

foreach takes a Consumer as an argument. If you think about it, the only useful thing you could do with such a method is to change the world (ie, mutate a state).

The opposite of that would a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), a function that doesn't mutate any state, it takes an input, and returns something, for example

```
Function<Integer,Integer> fn = x -> x*x;
```

`fn` here doesn't have any side effects (it doesn't mutate anything), it receives an integer and peacefully returns its square.

Comment: why `println` is considerd as side effect? seems it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [`Consumer` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), a consumer must be declared with a method having the signature `void accept(T)`. As a result, the method cannot return a value. If it did not have a side effect it would have no capability of performing any effects whatsoever.

Comment: "If it did not have a side effect it would have no capability of performing any effects whatsoever." - tells everything

Answer (score 5):

Most functional interfaces are meant to be just that - *functional* interfaces, which strictly means they accept an input, make some calculations, and return an output. They're not supposed to modify any state. `Consumer` is the exception because it doesn't return any values; its purpose is solely to modify some state.